# Different answers of a quadratic equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

given $4x^2−4x-5=0$

we all know the solution

but what my teacher showed me is different

after we get the

\begin{align*}
x & = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{96}}{8}\\
x & = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{4 \cdot 24}}{8}\\
x & = \frac{4 \pm 2\sqrt{4 \cdot 6}}{8}\\
x & = \frac{4 \pm 4\sqrt{6}}{8}\\
x & = \frac{4(1± \sqrt{6})}{8}\\
\end{align*}
he canceled $4$ and $8$ so the $4$ becomes $1$ and the $8$ becomes $2$

$$x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{6}}{2}$$

Explain to me how did he do that?

Comment: $16$ is a factor of $96$, so you can factor that out of the square root.  $96=6\cdot 16$ so $\sqrt{96}=\sqrt{16}\cdot\sqrt{6}=4\cdot\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: Please be cautious with the last line of your post, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help.  You may want to rephrase your questions in the future.

Comment: You can see how I formatted your equations by right-clicking on the equations, then selecting Show Math as TeX Commands.  Also, please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typset mathematics on this site.

Comment: They call it simplification$$\frac48=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}\frac{4 \pm \sqrt{96}}{8} &= \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{16\cdot6}}{8} \\ &=\frac{4 \pm \sqrt{16}\sqrt{6}}{8} \\ &=\frac{4 \pm 4\sqrt{6}}{8} \\ &=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{6}}{2} \end{align*}

---

By the way, the correct solutions of $3x^2-2x+1$ would be:

$$\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4-12}}{6}$$

but these solutions are not real numbers.

Comment: thanks now i know, hahaha thank you very much

Comment: @TeitoKlein You are welcome. If you like my answer, then you can accept it. That is the StackExchange way of saying thank you.

Comment: @TeitoKlein Accepting an answer is also a good clue for people who find your question later--that this would be a good question to look at if they have a similar question (maybe it already gives them the answer they want), or if they're looking for questions that _need_ answers (intending to answer them), they can look at a different question.